# Set a random bootstrap 3 label class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Let's say I have to display 5 or 10 labels.
Is it possible for every different label to set a random label class? like info, primary, danger etc. in bootstrap 3.
I am generating the labels dynamically so I can set the class for all of them to be one, but I want each label to be different class.

edit: I am generating the labels dynamically in Laravel Blade view. What I want to say is that for each label there is, I want the label to have a random(one of the primary, success, info, warning, danger) class.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need its This,

```css
.phaedra-colors .label {
  color: #001713;
}
.phaedra-colors .label-default {
  background-color: #95a5a6;
}
.phaedra-colors .label-default[href]:hover,
.phaedra-colors .label-default[href]:focus {
  background-color: #7f8c8d;
}
.phaedra-colors .label-primary {
  background-color: #00A388;
}
.phaedra-colors .label-primary[href]:hover,
.phaedra-colors .label-primary[href]:focus {
  background-color: #007D68;
}
.phaedra-colors .label-success {
  background-color: #79BD8F;
}
.phaedra-colors .label-success[href]:hover,
.phaedra-colors .label-success[href]:focus {
  background-color: #659E78;
}
.phaedra-colors .label-info {
  background-color: #BEEB9F;
}
.phaedra-colors .label-info[href]:hover,
.phaedra-colors .label-info[href]:focus {
  background-color: #A5CC8A;
}
.phaedra-colors .label-warning {
  background-color: #FFFF9D;
}
.phaedra-colors .label-warning[href]:hover,
.phaedra-colors .label-warning[href]:focus {
  background-color: #D1D181;
}
.phaedra-colors .label-danger {
  background-color: #FF6138;
}
.phaedra-colors .label-danger[href]:hover,
.phaedra-colors .label-danger[href]:focus {
  background-color: #D6512F;
}

.flat-ui-colors .label-default {
  background-color: #95a5a6;
}
.flat-ui-colors .label-default[href]:hover,
.flat-ui-colors .label-default[href]:focus {
  background-color: #7f8c8d;
}
.flat-ui-colors .label-primary {
  background-color: #3498db;
}
.flat-ui-colors .label-primary[href]:hover,
.flat-ui-colors .label-primary[href]:focus {
  background-color: #2980b9;
}
.flat-ui-colors .label-success {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
}
.flat-ui-colors .label-success[href]:hover,
.flat-ui-colors .label-success[href]:focus {
  background-color: #27ae60;
}
.flat-ui-colors .label-info {
  background-color: #9b59b6;
}
.flat-ui-colors .label-info[href]:hover,
.flat-ui-colors .label-info[href]:focus {
  background-color: #8e44ad;
}
.flat-ui-colors .label-warning {
  background-color: #e67e22;
}
.flat-ui-colors .label-warning[href]:hover,
.flat-ui-colors .label-warning[href]:focus {
  background-color: #d35400;
}
.flat-ui-colors .label-danger {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}
.flat-ui-colors .label-danger[href]:hover,
.flat-ui-colors .label-danger[href]:focus {
  background-color: #c0392b;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h2>Default colors</h2>
<a class="label label-default" href="#">Default</a>
<a class="label label-primary" href="#">Primary</a>
<a class="label label-success" href="#">Success</a>
<a class="label label-info" href="#">Info</a>
<a class="label label-warning" href="#">Warning</a>
<a class="label label-danger" href="#">Danger</a>

<h2>Phaedra Colors</h2>
<div class="phaedra-colors">
  <a class="label label-default" href="#">Default</a>
  <a class="label label-primary" href="#">Primary</a>
  <a class="label label-success" href="#">Success</a>
  <a class="label label-info" href="#">Info</a>
  <a class="label label-warning" href="#">Warning</a>
  <a class="label label-danger" href="#">Danger</a>
</div>


<h2>Flat UI Colors</h2>
<div class="flat-ui-colors">
  <a class="label label-default" href="#">Default</a>
  <a class="label label-primary" href="#">Primary</a>
  <a class="label label-success" href="#">Success</a>
  <a class="label label-info" href="#">Info</a>
  <a class="label label-warning" href="#">Warning</a>
  <a class="label label-danger" href="#">Danger</a>
</div>
```

Or try using this, [Bootstrap Button Generator](http://blog.koalite.com/bbg/)

Comment: I am generating the labels dynamically in Laravel Blade view. What I want to say is that for each label there is, I want the label to have a random(one of the primary, success, info, warning, danger) class.